# Add field in a Gii form from another table

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table called child (id, name, sport_id), a table called sports (id, name), a table called parent (id, name) and a table called child_parent(id, child_id, parent_id).

I created the crud with Gii and I modified the child_parent to show not the id of the child and parent but the names, also made a dropdownlist for search and for the create form. But one thing I can't do is put an extra column on the index from called 'Sport', so I can filter childs/parents by sport. How can I do this?

Comment: What model are you using on this index? `child_parent` ?

Comment: Exactly. Im using child_parent model

Comment: ActiveRecord likely won't do you much good here.  You are probably best to use yii\db\Query and yii\data\SqlDataProvider with join() between child_parent and child and handling the filtering yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junction table is not necessary, you can use a self-referencing relation.

- node ( id, parent_id, sport_id, name)
- sport ( id, name )

With parent_id defaulting to NULL (root). If need be, you can add a rule or conditional visibility for fields that enforces children to have the same sport_id as the parent (unless its a root).

Now you can easily enable filtering by sport.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'sport_id',
    'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList(
        $searchModel, 
        'sport_id',
        ArrayHelper::map(Sport::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt' => '']
    ),
    'value' => function($model) {
        return $model->sport->name;
    }
],
```